# Finding miminum values by columns for a pandas DataFrame containing NaN elements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I'm trying to get the minimum values between two `pandas` `Series`. It happens that some of the elements within the series are `NaN`, and I want to get as result `NaN` when it's compared with a number.

### Why I used `np.min` function

I used `np.min` function. This is because I understand using `min` function would lead to errors as the output depends on the order within the list when `NaN` elements exist in the list.

As when I run:

```
import numpy as np
print min([1,np.nan])
print min([np.nan,1])
```

I get as result:

```
>>> 
1
nan
```

And when I run:

```
import numpy as np
print np.min([np.nan,1])
print np.min([1,np.nan])
```

I get what I expect instead:

```
>>> 
nan
nan
```

### Toy sample code for finding minimum values between two `pandas` Series

Taking previous results into account I used `np.min`function. However if I run following toy sample code with two `Series`, create a `DataFrame` and find the minimum, I get the numbers and not the `NaN` as I expect when `NaN` and numbers are compared.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
s2 = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0, np.nan])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([s1,s2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([s2,s1])
r1 = np.min(df1,axis=0)
r2 = np.min(df2,axis=0)
print r1
print r2
```

Which results in following print result:

```
>>> 
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    0.0
4    5.0
dtype: float64
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    0.0
4    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Hoewever I would expect result to be same as `Serie` `s2`, being `DataFrame` `df1`:

```
>>> df1
     0    1    2    3    4
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN
```

### Question

Is there a function I'm missing or I'm doing something wrong when finding minimum values for the `DataFrame` I created with the two Series? I want `NaN` to be the result when numbers and `NaN` elements are compared...

**Note**: I'm using `python 2.7` with `numpy 1.13.3` and `pandas 0.22.0`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. You want `NaN` to always be returned when comparing to *any* number?

Comment: Correct @RafaelC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, You can pass the `values` of the series to `np.min` as an `np.array`, and you get the behaviour you would expect from `np.min`:

```
>>> np.min(df2.values,axis=0)
array([nan, nan, nan,  0., nan])
>>> np.min(df1.values,axis=0)
array([nan, nan, nan,  0., nan])
```

You can also apply the argument `skipna=False` to `pands.DataFrame.min`, to consider `NaN` values as well:

```
>>> df1.min(axis=0, skipna=False)
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    0.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
>>> df2.min(axis=0, skipna=False)
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    0.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yup, I noted this too. But can you comment *why* this is the case? `np.min` docs (`help(np.min)`) suggest `NaN` values are always propagated.

Comment: I like the possibility to use `df1.min(skipna=False)` this is much more descriptive of what I'm doing and it results in what I want. It still remains unknown to me about why the need to use the values option for the DataFrames in order to `np.min` to work as expected...

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this is the definition of `np.minimum`

> Compare two arrays and returns a new array containing the element-wise
>   minima. **If one of the elements being compared is a NaN, then that
>   element is returned.** If both elements are NaNs then the first is
>   returned.

```
r1 = np.minimum(df1.loc[0, :], df1.loc[1, :])
r2 = np.minimum(df2.loc[0,:], df2.loc[1, :])
```

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote? Maybe I misunderstood the question, would be happy if downvoter could explain ;)

Comment: I'm curious too, this seems like a fine alternative that leads to OP's desired output. (+1 already) (Note, I got downvoted too, I'm guessing that neither of us explained *why* this happens)

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted here. Seems a downvote to the other useful question was also applied.

Comment: Would you please explain why `np.minimum(np.asarray(s1),np.asarray(s2))` leads to `array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  5.])` instead?

Comment: @CedricZoppolo Can't reproduce, yields `array([nan, nan, nan,  0., nan])` here

Comment: @RafaelC I'm using `python 2.7` and `numpy 1.13.3`, what about you?

Comment: @CedricZoppolo Python `3.6.5` and numpy `1.14.3`

Comment: @sacul well that might make sense, but I dont think there is anything to explain here becasue the function is spcifically designed to return NaN when this happens. It has been programmed this way from source (I guess that shoud be sufficient explanation haha)